Package soul clashes with package hyperref
Consider the following MWE
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[\hl{Trigonometry}]
  We have $\sin^{2}x+\cos^{2}x=1$ for every $x$.
\end{theorem}
\hl{Trigonometry}
\end{document}

When compiling it gives an error Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed
If you comment package hyperref it compiles nicely
What is even worse is that this happens on my new PC with Linux Mint 22 freshly installed, whereas on my old PC with Linux Mint 21 it compiles nicely in both cases.
I have seen here Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed but it didn't help.
Edit: here is the log, ase requested by @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.12.7)  7 DEC 2024 22:30
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**mwe
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-01-22>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo
File: bk10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count187
\c@chapter=\count188
\c@section=\count189
\c@subsection=\count190
\c@subsubsection=\count191
\c@paragraph=\count192
\c@subparagraph=\count193
\c@figure=\count194
\c@table=\count195
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2023/11/15 v3.01 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 274.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1350.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1354.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/soul/soul.sty
Package: soul 2023-06-14 v3.1 Permit use of UTF-8 characters in soul (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/soul/soul-ori.sty
Package: soul-ori 2023-06-14 v3.1 letterspacing/underlining (mf)
\SOUL@word=\toks17
\SOUL@lasttoken=\toks18
\SOUL@syllable=\toks19
\SOUL@cmds=\toks20
\SOUL@buffer=\toks21
\SOUL@token=\toks22
\SOUL@syllgoal=\dimen141
\SOUL@syllwidth=\dimen142
\SOUL@charkern=\dimen143
\SOUL@hyphkern=\dimen144
\SOUL@dimen=\dimen145
\SOUL@dimeni=\dimen146
\SOUL@minus=\count196
\SOUL@comma=\count197
\SOUL@apo=\count198
\SOUL@grave=\count199
\SOUL@spaceskip=\skip50
\SOUL@ttwidth=\dimen147
\SOUL@uldp=\dimen148
\SOUL@ulht=\dimen149
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hypertext links for LaTeX
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks23
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2023-11-26 v2.56 Cross-referencing by name of section
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)
))
\c@section@level=\count266
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count267
)
\@linkdim=\dimen150
\Hy@linkcounter=\count268
\Hy@pagecounter=\count269
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count270

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4179.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4184.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4187.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4194.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4199.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4446.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count271
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4784.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen151
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count272
\Field@Width=\dimen152
\Fld@charsize=\dimen153
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6063.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6068.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6071.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6078.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6083.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6088.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6093.
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count273
\c@Item=\count274
\c@Hfootnote=\count275
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hyperref driver for pdfTeX

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend package
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count276
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count277
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2022-07-10 v1.10 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 285.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip51
)
\c@theorem=\count278
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-01-04 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count279
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
) (./mwe.aux)
\openout1 = `mwe.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count280
\scratchdimen=\dimen154
\scratchbox=\box52
\nofMPsegments=\count281
\nofMParguments=\count282
\everyMPshowfont=\toks24
\MPscratchCnt=\count283
\MPscratchDim=\dimen155
\MPnumerator=\count284
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count285
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks25
)
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 7.
 (./mwe.out) (./mwe.out)
\@outlinefile=\write3
\openout3 = `mwe.out'.



./mwe.tex:8: Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed.

See the soul package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.8 \begin{theorem}[\hl{Trigonometry}]
                                      
I came across hyphenatable material enclosed in group braces,
which I can't handle. Either drop the braces or make the material
unbreakable using an \mbox (\hbox). Note that a space
also counts as possible hyphenation point. See page 4 of the manual.
I'm leaving a black square so that you can see where I am right now.

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 9.
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}

] (./mwe.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-01-22>
 ***********
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `mwe.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 8692 strings out of 476057
 133742 string characters out of 5792522
 1925975 words of memory out of 5000000
 30646 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 559389 words of font info for 40 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 81 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 75i,5n,79p,263b,435s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on mwe.pdf (1 page, 52787 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 38 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 24 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 2 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)


Please show your .log file so we can see which version of texlive you have.

I can't reproduce your error.

The only way I can generate the soul-related error message is if I also load the amsthm package.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz : I added the log file, as requested

@Mico : actually, in the original file I had  amsthm loaded. Yet, when nailing down the source of the error, on my system ```amsthm`` proved to be unnecessary: I still get the error with the code provided in the question, albeit I get the error ONLY in Linux Mint 22 and NOT in Linux Mint 21 with the very same file. I have got absolutely no idea of why it is like that.

Instead of using the soul package and its \hl macro, would you be willing to use the ulem package (preferably with the option normalem) and replacing \hl{Trigonometry} with \uline{Trigonometry}?

@Mico Well, actually in my original file I use also the package xcolor, so the result is to have the text highlighted, not underlined ...

Why don't you use the colorizing machinery of the xcolor package directly? Why go a circuitous route instead?

it errors in texlive 2023 but works in texlive 2024. But there is really no reason to use soul in this place - there is no line break, a simple \underline should work fine.

@UlrikeFischer - The OP has indicated in a comment that he [? - "brad"] isn't actually underlining, but instead colorizing. That said, there's still no good reason for using soul, right?

@UlrikeFischer and Mico : it took me quite some time to nail down this MWE from a book of over 500 pages which, on Mint 21, compiles flawlessly, not even an underfull. I took care to strip all packages but the problematic ones, in order to point out the problem. On the other hand, in the book I do colorize and, possibly, it stretches over lines. Soul is the only option I could find. In any case, just saying "use something else" may be a (possibly useful) workaround, but doesn't address the issue which if it doesn't depend on some my wrong doing, then is a bug and is worth being signaled

Anyway, meanwhile I have already found out a couple of different workaraounds, in order to be able to go on with my work. So if, as @UlrikeFischer says, this issue has already been addressed in texlive 2024, then may be I just need to wait for the upcoming Mint 22.1, due in Christmas time, and see if it ships the new texlive

Soul is quite fragile. A better option is to use lualatex and the lua-ul package.

Yes: that is one of the workaround I have found. The only point is that I never used lualatex so I am a bit wary of the switch... :(  But the test I did was smooth. The other workaround was, as you suggested... :) , to simply use \colorbox anywhere there is no line break: as it happens, the problem shows up only in the optional text of a statement, and that never stretches over a line.
